# prototype: deep scope of "this" to access instance's scope

Tags: javascript, prototype

How can the the top-most scope can be cached in order to be used deeper in the prototype later, like so:

```
var Game = function(id){
   this.id = id;
};

Game.prototype = {
  board : {
    init: function(){
       // obviously "this" isn't the instance itself, but will be "board"
       console.log(this.id);
    }
  }
}

var game = new Game('123');
game.board.init(); // should output "123"
```

### update:

Well now that I think about it, I can use [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)/[`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and pass the context...

```
game.board.init.apply(game);
```

Comment: Its like a static class, when you make object in prototype, its same object in all instances.. its means **(new Game()).board == Game.board** and **(new Game()).board.init == Game.board.init** .. and it means, 'this' of object inner another object is parent object, its means 'this' in inner init function is same with board: in init function -> **this == Game.board**

Comment: Will you need multiple instances of Game? Looks like it should be a namespace (in the form of an object literal); then you'd have constructors and prototypes for Board, and whatever else you need.

Comment: yes I must have instances. unknown number of them.

Comment: I've decided to use 'Apply' after all

Comment: @vsync: If you use `apply`, you will be calling the `init` method as a member of the `game` instance, not as a member of the `board` instance. Then it would be better to just put the members of the `board` object in the `Game` object to start with, and ditch the `board` object completely.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Organize prototype javascript while perserving object reference and inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884096/organize-prototype-javascript-while-perserving-object-reference-and-inheritance)

Answer (score 2):

As you only have one instance of the `board` object, there is no way for it to know what you used to access it. Using `game.board` or `Game.prototype.board` to access the object gives exactly the same result.

If you don't want to create one `board` object for each `Game` instance, you have to tell the `board` object which `Game` object it should consider itself to belong to for each call:

```
game.board.doSomething(game);
```

or:

```
Game.prototype.board.doSomething(game);
```

#### Edit:

To create one board for each `Game` instance, make a constructor for `Board`, and make the board object aware of the `Game` instance that it belongs to:

```
function Game(id) {
  this.id = id;
  this.board = new Board(this);
}

Game.prototype = {
};

function Board(game) {
  this.game = game;
}

Board.prototype = {
  init: function(){
    console.log(this.game.id);
  }
};

var game = new Game('123');
game.board.init(); // outputs "123"
```

Comment: `board` has things inside it that interacts with each specific instance (since every game has different board), so calling it directly won't be a good idea.

Comment: @vsync You added `board` to `Game.prototype`, so all Game instances share the same board. Maybe that's not what you actually want, considering your comment above.

Comment: @vsync: If you want each `Game` instance to have their own board, you have to change your implementation so that you create one board for each `Game` instance. Then the board can have an owner, and can be made aware of which it is. See the code that I added above.

Comment: I've designed it exactly the way I want it, with shared prototype to all instances. I've being coding JS for 8 years, i'm not new to this..but the thing is, I was wandering perhaps there was a way to save the scope with some closures trickery..sometimes JS requires more creativity of the mind

Comment: steaks's answer was the thing I was looking for, a JS trickery to make the innermost prototyped objects know about the uppermost scope. neat.

Comment: @vsync: No, that's not what you are looking for. That is not a good solution, because it only works if you only ever have one single instance of the `Game` object. If you create another instance of the `Game` object, it will steal the board from the first instance.

Comment: yep duhh "WHAT WAS I THINKING?!" lol, obviously the prototype will change for every instance...

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as 'deeper in the prototype'. "this" will always be the object that you're calling it on, unless that's changed through being a callback or various ways to rebind. You'll have less sanity loss if you split up your concepts and link them together:

```
Board = function (game) {
    this.game = game;
}

Board.prototype.init = function () {
    console.log(this.game.id);
}

Game = function () {
    this.id = 123;
    this.board = new Board(game);
}

Game.prototype = {};
```

Alternatively, if you're hellbent on making it all use the same base, you can do some crazy hack like..

```
Game = function () {
    this.id = 123;
    var self = this;
    for(var p in this.board) {
        var property = this.board[p];
        if(typeof property == 'function') {
            this.board[p] = function (method) {
                return function () {
                    method.apply(self, arguments);
                }
            }(property)
        }
    }
}
```

This is a total hack, and it'll make your coworkers hate you. (If you're using the underscore library, there's a bindAll function that helps with this stuff)

Comment: yeah obviously...but I don't want to change my code, which is written and split everything to be "flat" functions without nesting in namespace which makes sense, this is ugly programing...

Comment: also I have a ton of inner functions and it would be a mess writing `Game.prototype.something= function(){ .. }` all the time, I just think it is not worth the easy fix I gain for the core scope access

Comment: The hack does not work as it misses a closure for `property`. It should just use ES5 `bind`: `this.board[p] = this.board[p].bind(this);`

Comment: You're right in that it was missing a closure. However, it shouldn't "just use" bind - IE8 doesn't support it, and that's still a 'popular' browser.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE

You must make a new instance of for each game if you don't want to provide scope for each function.  If you want, you can make board private to `Game` by making the board constructor a variable in the `Game` constructor function

```
var Game = function(id){
    //Keep board private to Game
    var boardClass = function (scope) {
        this.scope = scope;
        this.init = function () {
            if ( this.scope instanceof Game ) {
                console.log(this.scope.id);
            }
        };
    };
    this.id = id;
    //Instantiate a new board for each game
    this.board = new boardClass(this);
};

var game = new Game(123);
//Logs 123
game.board.init();

var game2 = new Game(456);
//Logs 456
game2.board.init()

//Still Logs 123
game.board.init();
```

**Don't use the code below because, as *Guffy* points out, one board object is shared between all instances of Game.  So the solutions below do not work for multiple Games.**

---

You could force game.board.init to make `this` refer to an instance of game.

```
var Game = function(id){
    this.id = id;
    this.board.game = this;
};

Game.prototype = {
    board : {
        game: {},
        init: function() {
            //check if this is an instance of board by seeing if it has a game property
            if(this.game) {
                //make this refer to the game if it is referring to the board
                this.init.apply(this.game);
            }
            console.log(this.id);
        }
    }
}

var game = new Game(123);
//Logs 123
game.board.init();

var game2 = new Game(456);
//Logs 456
game2.board.init();

//Logs 456...oops!
game.board.init();
```

Or you could simply make the instance of game a property on the board.

```
var Game = function(id){
    this.id = id;
    this.board.scope = this;
};

Game.prototype = {
    board : {
        init: function(){
           // can check if the scope is what we want it to be
           if( this.scope instanceof Game )
                console.log(this.scope.id);
        }
    }
}

var game = new Game(123);
//Logs 123
game.board.init();

var game2 = new Game(456);
//Logs 456
game2.board.init();

//Logs 456...oops!
game.board.init();
```

Comment: You are a good developer my friend, I love this second part. I've re-written it to better match

Comment: That only works for one single instance of the `Game` object.

Comment: @Guffa you are right.  Developers should not use this answer as is.

Comment: @Guffa I think my revised solution should work for multiple instances of Game.

Comment: Neither of these is a good solution. 1) because of the unnecessary "class" (with extra prototype object, while only one "instance" is needed) 2) because it overwrites the properties on that *one* shared board object 3) because it has the same problem as 2

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
var Model = function() {this.b = 2;};
Model.prototype.a = function() {
   console.log(this); 
   var that = this;
   this.a.on = function(){
     console.log(that); console.log(m.b);
   };
}

var m = new Model();
m.a();
m.a.on();
```

You need to do two things

- Create set the method inside the prototype method, means `on` should be defined inside `a` so that it has access to `this`.
- Create a copy of the parent reference in `that` and use it inside `on`

Answer (score 0):

It's a very bad idea to do so, as it leads to very strange behaviour in some cases, but it's possible:

```
var Model = function(x) { this.x = x };

Object.defineProperty(Model.prototype, 'a', (function() {
  var lastSelf;
  function get() { return lastSelf.x }
  get.on = function () { return lastSelf.x * 2 };
  return { get() { lastSelf=this; return get } };
})());

var m = new Model(17);
console.log(m.a(), m.a.on());
```

> Why? I see your answer below, trying to realize what are bad cases.

You can't pass `a` through the variable.
You must grant access to `on` immediately after getting property `a` of the same object:

```
var m1 = new Model(1), m2 = new Model(3);
console.log(m1.a(), m2.a(), m1.a.on(), m2.a.on()); // 1 3 2 6 - ok
var a1 = m1.a, a2 = m2.a;
console.log(m1.a(), m2.a(), a1.on(), a2.on()); // 1 3 6 6 - ooops!
console.log(m1.a(), m2.a(), m1.a(), a1.on(), a2.on()); // 1 3 1 2 2 - ooops!
```