# Keep `this` on prototype's object

Tags: object, coffeescript, prototype, this

I am trying to build a small javascript library for study purposes. I have an object inside a prototype that has some functions inside. I would like to access `this` (the one that has `valueOf` and stuff) from inside the functions, but `this` now brings me only the object parent to the functions.

My code (coffee):

```
HTMLElement.prototype.on =
  click: (action) -> @valueOf().addEventListener('click', action, false)
                     # I'd like this to work,
                     # but `this` here refers to the `on` object
```

Is this possible? I know I'm kinda reinventing the wheel, but as I said, it's for study purposes, so that's the idea.

Comment: In short: No, it's impossible.

Comment: Which `this` are you referring to? You said "(the one that has valueOf and stuff)" but I am not understanding.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Organize prototype javascript while perserving object reference and inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884096/organize-prototype-javascript-while-perserving-object-reference-and-inheritance) or [prototype: deep scope of “this” to access instance's scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16502467/prototype-deep-scope-of-this-to-access-instances-scope)

Comment: I believe it's a duplicate, but I hadn't seen this other question before. I'll check if it answers my question...

Comment: @Alberto: the `this` which contains the `HTMLElement` instance's data.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure about the "this" the OP is referring to but I'll try to answer:

Let's first compile your coffee-script code to javascript:

```
HTMLElement.prototype.on =
  click: (action) =>> @valueOf().addEventListener('click', action, false)

HTMLElement.prototype.on = {
  click: function(action) {
    return this.valueOf().addEventListener('click', action, false);
  }
};
```

Ok, all right. In javascript the value of `this` in a function can be determined by many factors, one of which is a MemberExpression. When you call a function with `a.b()`, where `a` is an object, `this` inside the function `b` will be bound to `a`. In your case you are probably calling the function like that:

```
element.on.click(...);
```

The issue is that `element.on` is itself an object. The expression will evaluate to

```
(element.on).click(...);
```

and the value of `this` in the `click` function will be the object `prototype.on`, not `element`.

Basically, don't do it that way. It will be a pain to bind `this` to the HTMLElement instance. Put the function directly on the prototype. The only solution I can think of (terrible, shame on me) is:

```
element.on.click.bind(element)(...)
```

Comment: That indeed is my problem. Now I just need a solution that is better than repeating `element`, but I'm starting to think that's impossible with javascript (that is, if something is impossible in JS).

Comment: @AndréLeria well, just put functions on the prototype, not objects. You could have something like prototype.onClick, or prototype.bind('click', function () { ... }).

Comment: I know, but that already exists. I just wanted to organize stuff better. But I think I've worked around this, and I may soon be posting my resolution to it here...

Comment: @AndréLeria I don't think it is "better organization" but you can do something like `function EventHandler(element) { ... }`; `function Element() { this.on = new EventHandler(this); }`

Comment: That looks like the way to go. I was thinking on something like that, but built directly on top of a coffee class. The solution is basically keeping an instance of `this` inside another object, as `this` itself will always be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, the solution is the => Operator.

http://coffeescript.org/#fat-arrow