# Javascript object - accessing parent's parent

Tags: javascript, class, oop

Lets say we have the code:

```
var MyConstructor = (function() {
  var constructor = function(name, type) {
    this.name = name;
    this.type = type;
  };

  constructor.prototype: {
    init: function() {
      console.log(this.name);
      console.log(this.type);
    },
    errors: {
      message: function() {
        return "error";
      },
      presence: function() {
        // how do I access the each method off of the prototype in a clean manner?
        ?.each(function() {
          console.log('iteration');
        }); 
      }
    },
    each: function(cb) {
      this.type.forEach(function(t) {
        cb();
      });
    };
  };

  return {
    constructor: constructor
  };
});
```

I have a constructor with some methods, but also has an object `errors` with methods belonging to that object. How does `errors` access the constructor's methods?

Comment: Depends on how you call `presence`. You probably have to create/bind the function. For each instance in the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way for the `errors` object to know its "parent" directly. It's a different object, and technically you could grab a reference to it and make it a property of some other object.

There are a few ways to approach a solution.

You could move the declaration of `errors` into the constructor function and use a closure to keep a reference to the parent. This way `errors` is still a distinct object that you can reference. You just can't use `prototype` because you need the closure scope.

```
var constructor = function(name, type) {
  var errorParent = this;
  this.name = name;
  this.type = type;
  this.errors = {
    message: function() {
      return "error";
    },
    presence: function() {
      // access the parent's each() method
      errorParent.each(function() {
        console.log('iteration');
      }); 
    }
  },
};
```

A second alternative would be to make the `message` and `presence` methods become members of the constructor's prototype. Now you can keep the `prototype` structure, but there is no `errors` object.

```
constructor.prototype: {
  init: function() {
    console.log(this.name);
    console.log(this.type);
  },
  errors_message: function() {
      return "error";
  },
  errors_presence: function() {
      this.each(function() {
        console.log('iteration');
      }); 
  },
  each: function(cb) {
    this.type.forEach(function(t) {
      cb();
    });
  };
};
```

A third alternative is to make `Errors` an entirely separate class and create an instance `errors` within your constructor. Then the `errors` object would have an explicit reference to the object it is responsible for managing.

```
var constructor = function(name, type) {
  this.name = name;
  this.type = type;
  this.errors = new Errors(this);
};
```

...and elsewhere in the code...

```
function Errors(object) {
  this.object = object;
};
Errors.prototype.message = function() {
  return "error";
};
Errors.prototype.presence = function() {
  this.object.each(function() {
    console.log('iteration');
  }; 
};
```

The third approach seems the cleanest to me, but you'll have to decide which approach fits your application best.

P.S. As an aside, I know JavaScript object literals are all the rage for declaring entire classes, but many times (as in this case) using them actually restricts the way developers think about the code instead of enlightening them. IMHO.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer. I was looking for a way without changing my code, but the more and more I read, creating a class out of errors seems to be the cleanest way to do it for what I need. I'm not bound to literals, just needed a namespaced way of going about my errors. The last example does what I was as well as reading up on this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884096/organize-prototype-javascript-while-perserving-object-reference-and-inheritance.

Comment: You are welcome, and thank you for accepting the answer. It would benefit me (and others too!) if you up-vote the answer as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could bind the method so `this` will always be a reference to the constructor, not to the caller.

```
var MyConstructor = (function() {
  var constructor = function(name, type) {
    this.name = name;
    this.type = type;
  };

  constructor.prototype: {
    errors: {
      presence: (function() {
        // this is the constructor.
        this.each(function() {
          console.log('iteration');
        }); 
      }).bind(this)
    }
  };

  return {
    constructor: constructor
  };
});
```

Comment: I `console.log(this)` in `presence` and get window, any idea why? Shouldn't it be `constructor`?

Comment: Try `.bind(constructor)` rather than `.bind(this)`.

Comment: You want to bind to an instance, don't you? That will never be available on the prototype, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16502467/prototype-deep-scope-of-this-to-access-instances-scope?lq=1

Comment: Oh dang, I need to read up more.