# Creating functions in function prototypes for Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, prototype

How do I properly create a function within a function prototype? 
What I have is this:

```
    <body>
    <p id="demo"></p><script>
function person(first, last, age, eye) {
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    this.age = age;
    this.eyeColor = eye;
}
person.prototype.name = function() {
    return {
        myFunc: function() {
          this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
       }
      }
};

var myFather = new person("John", "Doe", 50, "blue");

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
"My father is " + myFather.name().myFunc; 
</script>

</body>
```

When I run this it returns "My father is function () { this.firstName + " " + this.lastName; }" , but I was expecting John Doe.

Comment: you're not calling `myFunc`, you're just returning the function itself. if you want to invoke `myFunc`, then it should `myFather.name().myFunc()`

Comment: What's a "function prototype"?

Comment: @MarcB: Yes, [although even that wouldn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16502467/prototype-deep-scope-of-this-to-access-instances-scope)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need call function, add `()` to `myFunc`. In your example you added reference to internal function.

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "My father is " + myFather.name().myFunc();
```

Also add `return` to `myFunc`. To get properties from parent scope - save reference to `this`

```
person.prototype.name = function () {
  var _this = this;

  return {
    myFunc: function () {
      return _this.firstName + " " + _this.lastName;
    }
  }
};
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/hafuzi/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: This solution works, Thanks! I guess my usage of 'this' was incorrect in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Myfunc is a function. When you call it, call like `myfunc()`

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling `myFunc` and also that function does not return anything. I find this cleaner and a better way to define the funciton prototype:

```
function Person(first, last, age, eye) {
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    this.age = age;
    this.eyeColor = eye;
}
Person.prototype = {
    name: function() {
          return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
       }
};
```

Note that `name` now returns `return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;`.

Then simply:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "My father is " + myFather.name();
```

Comment: even cleaner: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17474390/defining-a-javascript-prototype