# How to create a 'chaining' JavaScript API with intermediate 'fluent' verbage?

Tags: javascript, oop, methods, chaining

I am creating js sdk, where I am looking for creating user (API)/ user call function like;

```
var user = new user();

user.message.to("username").get.friendlist(function(data){
    //process data received from callback.
});
```

Now, I know that method chaining can be done, and I am able to make something like

```
function User(Name) {
    this.uname = Name;
}

User.prototype = {
    constructor: User,

    MessageTo: function (username) {
        this.uname = username;
        return this;
    },

    getFriendList: function (callback) {
        callback("My list");
    }
}
```

and I can use it as below after creating object of User();

```
user.messageTo("username").getFriendList(function(data){
});
```

But I have no Idea about how to get the method call like what I am looking for as;

```
user.message.to("username").get.friendlist(function(data){
});
```

Evan I am not sure if it is possible or not. Any help or pointer with same regards is appreciated.

Comment: Can you please show us how you are able to make the `getFriendList` chaining example?

Comment: To me `.get('friendlist', function(data) {` makes more sense.

Comment: @Vohuman , yes its a option but I have to do it other way ...!!

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884096/organize-prototype-javascript-while-perserving-object-reference-and-inheritance or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16502467/prototype-deep-scope-of-this-to-access-instances-scope

Comment: I don't understand. What's wrong with `user.messageTo("username").getFriendList(callback)`?

Comment: @AaditMShah yes, there is nothing wrong with it, it just to make more verbiage..!

Comment: Why? You are just making your program more complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As, commented by other member, there are other option to do same thing, but as I have to do it the way I needed here is how we managed to do that.

This solution fits in my requirement, so may be not best suited in other cases.

**sdk.js**

```
var User = function(){
UserName = null;
this.message = {

to : function(uname){

  UserName = uname   
  alert('called to '+uname);

  this.get = {
    friendlist : function(callback){
      console.log('called friendlist');
        callback('Hello friendlist :: '+ UserName);
    }
  }
  return this;
  }
  };
}
```

and using it like;

```
  var user1 = new User();

  user1.message.to('H.Mahida').get.friendlist(function(data){
      alert('call back says '+ data);
  });
```

Here is link to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hmahida/58gb3eyu/)

Hope it may be useful to some one or guide in same direction...!!!