# Accesing `this` value when the prototype contains an object?

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

I have a *class* like this:

```
 function Foo() {
   this._current = -1;
 }
 Foo.prototype.history = {};
 Foo.prototype.history.back = function () {
   if (this._current === undefined) {
     return alert("this._current is undefined");
   }
   --this._current; // `this` is the history object
 };
```

How can I access the `Foo` instance in the `back` method?

I solution I see is to do something like this:

```
var f = new Foo();
f.history.back = f.history.back.bind(f);
```

Is there a *better* solution? Doing that for every `Foo` instance does not sound good for me.

---

Here is an example:

```js
function Foo() {
  this._current = -1;
}
Foo.prototype.history = {};
Foo.prototype.history.back = function() {
  if (this._current === undefined) {
    return alert("this._current is undefined");
  }
  --this._current; // `this` is the history object
};

var f = new Foo();
f.history.back();
```

I know it's supposed to be so, but what's the correct way to solve this type of problem?

Comment: Your `.bind()` solution won't really work - every `Foo` instance *shares* the same `history` object.

Comment: Maybe dumb question .. but why isn't `history` a property of the instance instead of the prototype?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884096/organize-prototype-javascript-while-perserving-object-reference-and-inheritance or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16502467/prototype-deep-scope-of-this-to-access-instances-scope

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fundamental problem in your code is that you have only one `history` object shared between all instances of `Foo`. You must make it one `history` per instance. A solution would be this:

```js
function FooHistory(foo){
 this._foo = foo;
}
FooHistory.prototype.back = function() {
  if (this._foo._current === undefined) {
    return alert("this._foo._current is undefined");
  }
  this._foo._current--; 
};

function Foo() {
 this._current = -1;
 this.history = new FooHistory(this);
}
var f = new Foo();
f.history.back();
```

(you probably want to have `_current` in the `FooHistory` instance instead of the `Foo` instance, I tried to change as little code as possible)

Note that other solutions are possible, depending on the larger view. If you don't have any state to store in the history object then you could also have `Foo.prototype.history()` return an object with a property linking back to the `Foo` instance. Then you would call `f.history().back()`.