# Javascript: Call object function from within a function object

Tags: javascript, function, oop

my problem seems to be that my object function is not visible if i call it from within an object of functions. Example Code:

```
function foo()
{
   this.bar = function() 
              { 
                 alert("hit me!"); 
              }

   this.sna = { 
                 fu:   function () 
                       {
                          this.bar();
                       }
              };

}
```

`this` seems to refer to `sna` instead of `foo`. How do i adress `foo`? `this.parent` does not work.

Comment: I suggest you do some research about understanding `this` and scoping in javascript - it's a too wide topic to be explained in a short answer on SO

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16502467/prototype-deep-scope-of-this-to-access-instances-scope. You cannot access `bar` using `this` when you called your method by `….sna.fu.bar()`, as it does reference `…sna.fu`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a variable to refer to `this`(Foo). See [this - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

```js
function Foo() {
    this.bar = function() {
        console.log("hit me!");
    };

    var that = this;

    this.sna = {
        fu: function() {
            that.bar();
        }
    };

}

var foo = new Foo();
foo.bar();
foo.sna.fu();
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to add a reference to `this`:

```
function foo() {

  var _t = this;

  this.bar = function() { };

  this.child = {
    this.foo = function() {
      _t.bar():
    };
  };

}
```