# Why is this Javascript code producing an error?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am not able to understand why this code is not working. I am trying to understand the prototype in Javascript. If I am declaring a new function inside a function then why am I not able to call that function?

```
<script>
  function Person(first) {
    this.firstName = first;                  
  }

  Person.prototype.name=function() {
    this.addLastNameInner=function() {
    return this.firstName+" Appended last name";   
    }                
  }

  Person.prototype.name.addLastName=function() {
    return this.firstName+" Appended last name";    
  }

  var pr=new Person('john');
  alert(pr.name.addLastNameInner());//Not working
  alert(pr.name.addLastName());//working fine
</script>
```

Comment: You're setting `name` to a function on to which you add the property `addLastName`.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve, but `addLastNameInner` won't exist until you call `name`, and even then it will be added to the `Person` instance, not as a property of the `name` function.

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884096/organize-prototype-javascript-while-perserving-object-reference-and-inheritance
and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16502467/prototype-deep-scope-of-this-to-access-instances-scope

Comment: Your code says *`.name` is a function that when called will create a new function `addLastNameInner` on `this`*. If you want `name` to be an object with properties, create it as an object with properties, not as a function.

Answer (score 0):

To make your code work, you need to change the way you declare `name`:

```
Person.prototype.name = {
  addLastNameInner: function() {
    return this.firstName+" Appended last name";   
  }
};
Person.prototype.name.addLastName = function() {
  return this.firstName + " Appended last name";    
};
```

Because, what you are doing as `.name` is that you are not initializing it with a `new` keyword. And it cannot be done that way. The `.name` **must** be an `Object` with the functions.

Comment: `firstName` is a property on the `Person` object, so you can't do `this.firstname` in either of these functions.  OP's intention is really not clear.

Comment: Ah... I understand that. Is it possible for you to edit my answer?

Comment: Uh... no.  I don't think this question is answerable as it stands.

Answer (score -1):

There are some misconceptions about the scope of objects and functions in the code. I hope the below code is what you want.

```
    function Person(first) {
        this.firstName = first;
    }
    Person.prototype.name={
        addLastNameInner:function(pr){
              return pr.firstName+" Appended last name";   
        }
    }
    Person.prototype.name.addLastName=function(pr){
        return pr.firstName+" Appended last name";    
    }
    var pr=new Person('john');
    alert(pr.name.addLastNameInner(pr));//Working fine
    alert(pr.name.addLastName(pr));//working fine
```