# JavaScript: How to reference the top/root of a Class?

Tags: javascript, class, reference, this

So I have this problem:

```
class ClassName {
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    someObject = {
        someFunction() {
            console.log(this.value);
        }
    }
}
```

The `this.value` of `someFunction()` doesnt reference the value defined within the constructor, it is because `someFunction()` is part of the `someObject` Object and `this` references the Object.
**So how can I reference the top/root of the Class within Objects/Properties of it to access values and properties there?** I can also work with each Function being at the top level, but grouping them is way clearer.

Comment: You don't. That's why you don't use objects to group methods. (Though in your case they're not normal *methods* anyway, they're instantiated with every single instance - if you really want this, you might consider not using `class` syntax at all)

Comment: Not using `class` syntax, but have a look at [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884096/organize-prototype-javascript-while-perserving-object-reference-and-inheritance) [old questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16502467/prototype-deep-scope-of-this-to-access-instances-scope)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an [`arrow-function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) in order not to create a new scope:

```js
class ClassName {
  constructor(value) { this.value = value; }
  someObject = {
    someFunction: () => { console.log(this.value); }
  }
}

const obj = new ClassName(1);

obj.someObject.someFunction();
```

If you want to use a normal function, you need to use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind):

```js
class ClassName {
  constructor(value) { this.value = value; }
  someObject = {
    someFunction() { console.log(this.value); }
  }
}

const obj = new ClassName(1);

const fn = obj.someObject.someFunction.bind(obj);

fn();
```

Comment: thanks! But are arrow functions the only way?

Answer (score 2):

Just write the function as [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) like this to bind `this` at declaration time. As you can see in the example below, this syntax implies that `someObject` is being instantiated once per object instance, so you're not leveraging JavaScript's [prototypal inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) which is less good in terms of memory consumption.

```js
class ClassName {
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    someObject = {
        someFunction: () => console.log(this.value)
    }
}

const obj = new ClassName('test');

obj.someObject.someFunction();

const obj2 = new ClassName;

console.log(obj2.someObject === obj.someObject); // false
```