# putting prototyped methods inside of a js dict

Tags: javascript, oop

**EDIT:**  Here is a fiddle of why I cant do c.Get.Css() I made.... its involving deep copying.  http://jsfiddle.net/5YnhP/

I was prototyping some javascript:

```
var Control = {};
Control.Textbox = function(){};
Control.Textbox.prototype.Get = function(){};
Control.Textbox.prototype.Set = function(item){};
```

so that it says:

```
var c = new Control.Textbox();
c.Get();
```

I wanted to reform stuff slightly to organize methonds so it does something like:

```
var Control = {};
Control.Textbox = function(){
  this.Get = {};
  this.Set = {};
  this.Get.prototype.Css = function(){};
  //...
};
```

or should it say:

```
var Control = {};
Control.Textbox = function(){
  this.Get = {};
  this.Set = {};
};
Control.Textbox.Get.prototype.Css = function(){};
```

to then do something in the console such as:

```
var x = new Control.Textbox();
x.Get.Css();
x.Set.Css("herp","derp");
```

How would i go about doing this like i want?  I want to sort of organized different calls into groupings like that.

I am trying to find a solution but for the last few hours, i havent found one.

Comment: Why are you putting a `.prototype` property on the `Get` objects? They're not functions.
 Is there some reason you don't take your second example, but just do `this.Get.Css = function() {};` ?

Comment: i was trying to use GET to be a dict of functions.  

I was trying to do this.Get.Css = function(){}; but i figured if i was doing a deep copy of the object it would not work as functions usually dont copy in deep copies..  I started prototyping when a deep copy was glitching.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Organize prototype javascript while perserving object reference and inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884096/organize-prototype-javascript-while-perserving-object-reference-and-inheritance)

Comment: I did not see that one.  It seems that is done by adding additional classes.   I think i am going to agree, at the base, it looks like that is the question im doing, resolved via additional functions etc

Comment: Yes, what you are trying to accomplish is quite complicated (unless solved inefficient). Since you still seem to have trouble with understanding the `prototype` property, I'd recommend you to stay save and simple with `getCss` and `setCss` - no nesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you wrote it doesn't work, because normal objects don't have a `prototype` property, only functions have. So instead of this:

```
var Control = {};
Control.Textbox = function(){
  this.Get = {};
  this.Set = {};
  this.Get.prototype.Css = function(){};
  //...
};
```

You could simply write this:

```
var Control = {};
Control.Textbox = function(){
  this.Get = {};
  this.Set = {};
  this.Get.Css = function(){};
  //...
};
```

Now you would be able to do what you original wanted:

```
var x = new Control.Textbox();
x.Get.Css();
x.Set.Css("herp","derp");
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Tc8DX/)**

If, for whatever reason, you rely on having the `Css` method in the prototype of `Get`, you  can create `this.Get` by using a constructor function:

```
var get = function(){}
get.prototype.Css = function(){};
this.Get = new get();
```

In newer browsers you can also use `Object.create` to create an object with a specified prototype:

```
this.Get = Object.create({
    Css : function(){};
});
```

Comment: your first answer is what i had originally.  When copying the object, the Get.Css moves a reference to the function, and it seemed like it was passing the wrong data. back when running test scripts

Comment: @Fallenreaper yes, I read the comments a little late, that's why i updated my answer. But I don't understand what you want to happend when creating a deep object of the object. Do want the `Get` object to lose all its functions?

Comment: Please don't use `this.Get.__proto__.Css = …`. a) `__proto__` is not a standard and not supported in many environments b) It does not what you did think.

Comment: @Bergi I agree to your point a. That's why I wrote "some Browsers". But could you explain your point b) a little further? What exactly do you mean?

Comment: That code would be equivalent to `Object.getPrototypeOf(this.Get).Css = …` or just `Object.prototype.Css = …`. Definitely not what you had in mind, is it?

Comment: @Bergi ah I see. No, definitly not what I had in mind. I'm going to remove that part from the answer. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I posted a quick fiddle as to what i was trying to do.  It should be easy to follow.

Comment: @Fallenreaper So after you cloned `x` in your fiddle, you get the result `5` the next time you call your getter function. But what would be the desired result?

Comment: @basilikum Z is a clone of X, so it should print 5.  Then when you set Z to 4.  But both X and Z are now 4, where as, X should print 5 still and Z should print 4.  I didnt change X at all, so it shouldve been maintained as 5, instead of changing, which means the clones were not actual clones, but instead references to the same object.

Comment: @Fallenreaper ok I understand. I think I cannot solve your problem, to work the way you want it to. Here is your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5YnhP/1/ Maybe that would also work for you.

Comment: Looking at yours compared to mine, you more or less just removed the G= {}, and S={} and just put the function in there and it worked?  Mmmm... Well, it works... which is good.  I should also make use of the whole JS thing and possibly just tie gettings and setters in 1 function to resolve.  THank you.   I didnt want the G and S to be removed, but i can just redesign it accordingly.

Comment: @Fallenreaper it works because I use `this` inside of the function instead of the local variable `CONTROL`. `this` will always point to the object, your method belongs to. So if you copy your function to another object, `this` will refer to the new object, while `CONTROL` will still be the one defined in the old one. The problem is, that you can't use `this` in a sensable way, when your methods are inside of the objects `G` and `S`, because it will point to those objects instead of the object, that really holds the data.

Comment: yea, I was hoping CONTROL would help mitigate that issue.  I knew that was going to happen, but i guess CONTROL just wasnt doing what i wanted it to do.  It works, you have a solid answer, AND reasoning.  I thak you for that.  I will mark this as the correct one.