# Is it possible to create a custom prefix or namespace for jQuery functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a jQuery function/plugin:

```
$.fn.greenify = function() {
    this.css( "color", "green" );
}

$("a").greenify();
```

I want to have a prefix to apply for my functions, for example something like this:

```
$("a").colors.greenify();
```

In JavaScript function I can create an object that contains my functions:

```
var colors = new Object();
colors.greenify = function(el) {
    $(el).css( "color", "green" );
};

colors.greenify("a");
```

Is it possible to create a custom prefix on jQuery and have a function like this `$("a").colors.greenify();` work?

Thanks for help!

Comment: It looks like you want to namespace your plugins. Unfortunately, it'll lose the reference to the jQuery object. This could perhaps be done in browsers that support property accessors, but older browsers wouldn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Organize prototype javascript while perserving object reference and inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884096/organize-prototype-javascript-while-perserving-object-reference-and-inheritance)

Answer (score 3):

The closest you can get (without having to change jquery itself) is to make `$.fn.colors` a function that returns an object that contains the methods you want.

```
(function ($) {

    $.fn.colors = function () {
        var $this = this, ret = {
            greenify: function(){
                return $this.css("color", "green");
            }            
        };
        $this.data("colors",ret);
        return ret;
    };    

}(jQuery));

$("#demo").colors().greenify();

var colors = $("#demo").colors();
colors.greenify();

var colors = $("#demo").colors().data("colors");
colors.greenify();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ftLXh/

without the `()` after `colors`, you would lose access to the elements selected by `$("#demo")` without significant changes to the jquery core (you would have to hook into the core to have every jquery selection update a property on `$.fn.colors`)

Answer (score 1):

As Cookie Monster pointed at you could write a jquery plugin to do this:

```
(function($) {

    // here we go!
    $.colours = function(element, options) {

        // plugin's default options
        // this is private property and is  accessible only from inside the plugin
        var defaults = {
        }

        // to avoid confusions, use "plugin" to reference the 
        // current instance of the object
        var plugin = this;

        // this will hold the merged default, and user-provided options
        // plugin's properties will be available through this object like:
        // plugin.settings.propertyName from inside the plugin or
        // element.data('pluginName').settings.propertyName from outside the plugin, 
        // where "element" is the element the plugin is attached to;
        plugin.settings = {}

        var $element = $(element), // reference to the jQuery version of DOM element
             element = element;    // reference to the actual DOM element

        // the "constructor" method that gets called when the object is created
        plugin.init = function() {

            // the plugin's final properties are the merged default and 
            // user-provided options (if any)
            plugin.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
        }

        // public methods
        // these methods can be called like:
        // plugin.methodName(arg1, arg2, ... argn) from inside the plugin or
        // element.data('pluginName').publicMethod(arg1, arg2, ... argn) from outside 
        // the plugin, where "element" is the element the plugin is attached to;
        plugin.greenify = function() {
            $element.css( "color", "green" );

        }


        // fire up the plugin!
        // call the "constructor" method
        plugin.init();

    }

    // add the plugin to the jQuery.fn object
    $.fn.colours = function(options) {

        // iterate through the DOM elements we are attaching the plugin to
        return this.each(function() {

            // if plugin has not already been attached to the element
            if (undefined == $(this).data('colours')) {

                // create a new instance of the plugin
                // pass the DOM element and the user-provided options as arguments
                var plugin = new $.colours(this, options);

                // in the jQuery version of the element
                // store a reference to the plugin object
                // you can later access the plugin and its methods and properties like
                // element.data('pluginName').publicMethod(arg1, arg2, ... argn) or
                // element.data('pluginName').settings.propertyName
                $(this).data('colours', plugin);

            }

        });

    }

})(jQuery);
```

This allows you to call it thus:

```
$("a").colours();
$("a").data('colours').greenify();
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8HePL/1/)

the structure was taken from this [boilerplate code](http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/jquery-plugin-boilerplate-revisited/)

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the jQuery namespace then store a reference to the plugin on the color namespace when setting up the plugin.

```
$.fn.colors = function () {
    return this;
};
$.fn.greenify = $.fn.colors.greenify = function() {
    this.css( "color", "green" );
};
```

Now you can call `$('a').colors().greenify();`.

Comment: `this` in your greenify function will refer to `$.fn.colors`, not the result of `$()`.

Comment: at that point $.fn.colors is nothing more than an empty jquery plugin that doesn't add anything other than noise.

Comment: Does do what it says on the tin though.

Comment: yep. kinda like the question. why bother with adding a colors namespace at all? why not just call `$('a').greenify();` ?