# Call a nested function within a prototype method

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to call a function nested within a prototype method. I get undefined when I try to reference this nested function. example -

```
testObj.prototype.funcA = function() {
    var that = this;
    that.funcB.subFuncA(); //call nested function within funcB - undefined
}

testObj.prototype.funcB = function() {
    var subfuncA = function() {
        //call this function from funcA
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help provided.

Comment: Yeah... not possible. As simple as that.

Comment: `subfuncA` is local to `funcB`, and only exists at all when `funcB()` is called.

Comment: -1? Why? Okay, what the OP wants isn't possible because of the scope issue, but how will anyone learn anything if questions are downvoted based only on their technical level?

Answer (score 1):

`subfuncA` is locally scoped. It is not exposed outside `funcB` at all. This is (one way, sort of) how you create private functions in JS.

If you want `subfuncA` to be public, then stick it somewhere public.

```
testObj.prototype.funcA = function() {
    var that = this;
    that.funcB.subFuncA(); //call nested function within funcB - undefined
}

testObj.prototype.funcB = function() {
}

testObj.prototype.funcB.subfuncA = function () {

};
```

Comment: I don't think you really want to do that, [`this` doesn't work any more then](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15884332/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi — There isn't enough information about what `subfuncA` is supposed to do to know if `this` will be significant or not.

Comment: That's true. Since in the original code it wasn't a method either, this is probably fine, though as it doesn't seem to be an instance method at all it might be better to put it as a static helper function `TestObj.funcA`.