# Need help addEventListener and Object Oriented JavaScript: How to pass in argument and change its reference

Tags: javascript, oop, parameter-passing, dom-events, addeventlistener

Here is the jsfiddle to illustrate the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/mabqc2zs/4/

(same code below):

*JavaScript*

```
var namespace = namespace || {};

namespace.ExampleClass = function () {
    this.eventAdded = false;
    this.secondValue = null;

    this.doSomething = function() {
        var secondValue = this.secondValue;
    };

    this.event = { 
        eventAddedParam: this.eventAdded,
        addListener: function(el, type, eAP2) {
            if (!this.eventAddedParam) { // Ensures addEventListener registers only once.
                var eAP = this.eventAddedParam;
                el.addEventListener(type, function() { // Unable to add arguments to anonymous function
                    console.log("eAP2 value: " + eAP2); // false
                    console.log("eAP value: " + eAP); // true
                    try {
                        console.log("eventAddedParam value: " + eventAddedParam);
                    }
                    catch(e) {
                        console.log("Error: eventAddedParam variable is undefined"); 
                    }
                });
                eAP = true;
                this.eventAddedParam = true;
            }
        }
    };
};

var inst = new namespace.ExampleClass();

inst.event.addListener(document.getElementById("id1"), "focus", inst.eventAdded);
inst.event.addListener(document.getElementById("id1"), "focus", inst.eventAdded);
```

*HTML*

```
<input id="id1" type="text" />
```

I'm integrating `addEventListener` to some Object Oriented JavaScript code.

I wanted to add arguments to the anonymous function, i.e. `el.addEventListener(type, function()...` What I want to do is ensure `addEventListener` gets registered once. Hence, in the code, I check if `this.eventAddedParam` is true. It does work. Here is the problem. `this.eventAddedParam` refers to `eventAddedParam`, which is a literal object of `this.event`. When I set `eventAddedParam` to true, `eventAdded`, which is a public variable of the `ExampleClass`, is still set to false. This does does me no good.

Ultimately, what I want to do is change the value of `eventAdded` to true within the `addListener` function. I have not been able to figure this out.

And to further that, if possible, I'd like to make `eventAdded` a private variable, yet access it within the `addListener` function, but I have been able to figure that out, either.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update**

I have an updated jsfiddle, after making the necessary changes.

http://jsfiddle.net/mabqc2zs/8/

For some reason, my IE 11 Developer Toolbar was not registering local variables. But it does work.

Comment: a) Use variables instead of properties b) Don't use that `event.` extra object, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15884096/1048572)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Could you please elaborate, perhaps with an example, for `a)`? As for `b)`, I looked at the link you posted but I'm not sure how it relates to my question -- are you saying make `event` part of the namespace, not a class, and define it similar to `this.doSomething()`?

Comment: For a) use `var eventAdded = false;` for initialisation and then use `eventAdded` instead of `this.eventAddedParam` - making it a [private variable](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13418669/1048572) essentially. For b) I mean that you should put the `addListener` method directly on your `ExampleClass`, and not use `.event`

Comment: Thank you very much. I updated the jsfiddle with `addListener` as its own public method. I created `eventAddedLocal` as a test to see if the private variable would work in this case. it did. For some reason, my IE 11 Dev. Toolbar was not registering private class variables from within public methods. It only succeeded after I explicitly typed in the private variable in the public method in the code directly, not through IE. Strange but at least the concept works. Thanks again for your help.