# Javascript prototype organisation

Tags: javascript, prototype

With this organisation, is it possible to reference the "id" property?

```
  function house(id) {  this.id = id }

  house.prototype.buy  = function() {  }
  house.prototype.sell = function() {  }

  house.prototype.buy.makeOffer=function(){
    //how can id be printed?
    console.log( 'id = ' + this.????  )      
  }

  var h = new house(1)
  h.buy.makeOffer();
```

I am trying to figure out the best way to organize a lot of prototypes for an object.  As .buy will have a lot of sub-function an so will .sell()  ie:

```
  h.buy.makeOffer();
  h.buy.inspect();
  h.buy.counterOffer();
  h.buy.signContact();

  h.sell.prepare()
  h.sell.advertise()
  h.sell.reviewOffer()
```

Comment: `.buy.makeOffer` doesn't use prototype at all.

Comment: Be sure to double-check what `this` references in each place you use it.

Comment: Actually, this is a better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15884096/218196

Comment: You're probably after a classical inheritance language. Douglas Crockford [wrote](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html) on this subject.

Comment: The answer posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884096/organize-prototype-javascript-while-perserving-object-reference-and-inheritance looks like it defeats the reason for using prototypes as the each object duplicates the methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really not very easy to use a structure like this in Javascript:

```
house.prototype.buy.makeOffer=function(){
    //how can id be printed?
    console.log( 'id = ' + this.????  )      
}
```

The issue is that when you call that method on an instance of house like this:

```
var h = new house(1);
h.buy.makeOffer();
```

the `this` value in the `makeOffer()` method will point to the `buy` object in the prototype (which is your `buy` method) and it will NOT point to your `house` object.  That's just how method calls work in Javascript (`this` points to the object which had the method) which renders these nested methods when there's actual instance data that you want to reference via `this` very impractical.

---

The usual solution is to not implement the nesting.  Just integrate the names without an extra layer of objects like this:

```
house.prototype.buyMakeOffer=function(){
    //how can id be printed?
    console.log( 'id = ' + this.????  )      
}

var h = new house(1);
h.buyMakeOffer();
```

Comment: This solution is the only way I can see to do it.  Really I was hoping for a more organized solution.

Comment: @BrianMcGinity - there are ways to try to work around this issue, but IMO, they create far more complication than they justify.  You can just use a common prefix with an underscore `h.buy_makeOffer()` and get the same namespace separation as you get with the dot nomenclature so it's not actually a practical issue at all - just one that you like the way it looks better with the dot nomenclature.  But, unfortunately, Javascript makes that way messy.