# Access parent prototype scope from inside self-executing anonymous member function

Tags: javascript, scope, anonymous-function

I'm defining a Parent object, and I want it to have a child member object that has its own functions and private variables. In order to encapsulate the functions and variables, I'm adding a self-executing anonymous function to the Parent prototype.

Here is code demonstrating the problem:

```js
var Parent = function() {
    this.memberVariable = 'hello world';   
}

Parent.prototype.doSomething = function() {
    return this.childObject.doSomething();
};

Parent.prototype.childObject = function() {
    // instead of being Parent, `this` is the Window object. What is the best way to fix this?
    var that = this;
    
    return {
        doSomething: function() {
            // undefined, but should be 'hello world'
            return that.memberVariable;
        }
    }
}();

var parent = new Parent();
console.log(parent.doSomething());
```

One workaround I have is passing in the Parent scope to the child functions, but that seems weird, and it seems like there must be a better solution:

```js
var Parent = function() {
    this.memberVariable = 'hello world';   
}

Parent.prototype.doSomething = function() {
    // we pass in `this`
    return this.childObject.doSomething(this);
};

Parent.prototype.childObject = function() {
    return {
        doSomething: function(that) {
            return that.memberVariable;
        }
    }
}();

var parent = new Parent();
console.log(parent.doSomething());
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: You should look into the Module/Revealing Module pattern... http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript

Comment: You cannot have an IEFE to create a prototype method and expect to get a dynamic `this` inside there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Organize prototype javascript while perserving object reference and inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15884096/1048572)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initialize `childObject` inside the `Parent` constructor function. Otherwise, all instances of `Parent` will share the same `childObject`. That's probably not what you intend.

```
function Parent() {
  this.childObject = new Child(this); // or something like makeChild(parent), or just an object literal.
}

function Child(parent) {
  this.parent = parent;
}
```

Comment: That hadn't occurred to me because Parent is a singleton, so I wasn't thinking about the scope of the `childObject` definition. This is a much cleaner solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
Parent.prototype.doSomething = function() {
    return this.childObject.doSomething.call(this);
};
```

Or you could use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
Parent.prototype.childObject = function() {
    return {
        doSomething: (function() {
            // undefined, but should be 'hello world'
            return this.memberVariable;
        }).bind(this)
    }
}();
```

Comment: `.call()` is also one of the things I tried, but I don't like it very much either because it would have to be appended to every single call to `childObject`. Is that the best way to do it?