# JavaScript ES6: Grouping methods in es6 classes?

Tags: javascript, class, constructor, ecmascript-6

A few of us are trying to create a JavaScript library to quickly run JSON queries on a RESTful API.

What I'd like to do is group a set of methods relative to their purpose.

For example;

Through the API I am able to get user attributes. Instead of having all of these methods under the main object, I'd like to group them within the API class object.

i.e. 
Transform this:

```
myAPI.getUserById()
```

To This:

```
myAPI.User.getByID()

myAPI.User.getByName()
```

We'll use the code below as a simple example. How might I have my User methods nested within a User Object within myAPI Class??

```
class myAPI {
  constructor(url) {
    this.url = url;

    //Code to connect to instance...

  }

  getUserById(userId){
    // function
  }
}
```

**Solved**

```
class myAPI {
  constructor(url) {
    this.url = url;
    this.UserAPI = new UserClass(this);

    //Code to connect to instance...

  }

  getUserById(userId){
    // function
  }
}

class UserClass {
  constructor(parent){
    this.myAPI = parent;
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Organize prototype javascript while preserving object reference and inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15884096/1048572) - no, there's no good way to do this using only one class.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use composition:

```
class UserAPI {

    constructor(url) {
        this.url = url;
    }    

    getById() {
    }
}

class API {

    constructor(url) {

        this.url = url;
        this.User = new UserAPI(url);
    }
}

var myAPI = new API();

myAPI.User.getById();
```

This way, you can separate all kind of groups into classes. You can even discriminate different implementations of API's based on the user's requirements.

Comment: This is the basis of the service/model pattern used by many applications.

Comment: Thanks Tim. Never thought of it this way. Exactly what i was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: I have added an example in JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/MisterFantastic/0u50f7jy/

Comment: Confirmed working great in React pared with pure JS modules 