# Prototype sub objects this doesn't refer to base object

Tags: javascript, prototype

I was trying to make my code more readable and ran into an oddity with my build and events objects that I attached to the prototype. Is there a way to do this?

```
function Something(){
    this.$container = $('<div>');

    return this;
}

Something.prototype.build = {
    list: function(){
        this.$container.append(...);
    }
}
```

Currently what happens is when `build.list` calls `this`, `this` refers to the `build` object, not the `Something` object.

I can't quite figure out another way of using it this way without renaming everything to `buildList`, `buildComponentArray`, and etc. Semantics maybe.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Organize prototype javascript while perserving object reference and inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15884096/1048572) - just don't do that. Renaming to `buildList` etc. is fine.

Comment: Give up on sub-objects in this context as Javascript does not really support what you're trying to do in a simple manner.  Change `build.list` to `buildList` and life will be simple again.

Comment: very well then... silly me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a possible solution

```
function Something(){
    this.$container = "<div></div>";

    //this creates a new object in the prototype chain for every instance
    this.build = Object.create(this.build);
    for (var prop in this.build) {
        if (this.build.hasOwnProperty(prop) && typeof this.build[prop] === "function") {
            this.build[prop] = this.build[prop].bind(this);
        }
    }
    return this;
}

Something.prototype.build = {
    list: function(){
        console.log(this.$container);
    }
}
```

Basically you'll bind every function in your `this.build` object to a function bound to `this`. You could extract this in a utility function and then bind all nested object you need to this. I suppose it must be possible too by manipulating/build the prototype chain but I haven't found it.

I know most of you recommend refactoring, but I thought to put this out there just so you have a complete set of solutions.

**Edit**

As pointed out, you need to move the `build` interface to your constructor in order to have `this` bound correctly. This solution is just a way to do this without having to move your code.

**solution without using `Object.create`**

This one is cleaner and more explicitly states what it does without messing with prototypes.

```
 function Something(){
    this.$container = "<div></div>";

    var build = this.build;
    this.build = {};
    for (var prop in build) {
        if (build.hasOwnProperty(prop) && typeof build[prop] === "function") {
            this.build[prop] = build[prop].bind(this);
        }
    }
    return this;
}

Something.prototype.build = {
    list: function(){
        console.log(this.$container);
    }
}
```

Comment: That actually does *not* work, as it doesn't take into account multiple instances. You're binding the methods of the prototype `build` object to the last-created `Something` instance. You rather should simply move the `build` definition into the constructor.

Comment: @Bergi you're absolutely right, I updated my answer to include two working solutions.