# How to define a sub method using "prototype"?

Tags: javascript, class, methods, prototype

When I define a javascript class with methodes and submethodes this way it works:

```
function Controller () {
    this.OrdersSyncFreq = 3000; //ms

    this.syncOrders = function () {};
    this.syncOrders.start = function () { console.log("start was called"); };
    this.syncOrders.stop = function () { console.log("stop was called"); };
}
```

But how can I define the function `Controller.syncOrders.start()` later using "prototype"? Something like this does not work:

```
Controller.prototype.syncOrders.stop = function () {
    console.log("The NEW stop was called");
}
```

Comment: No, this never really worked, you cannot use `this` in those "methods". Just don't do it. Use regular prefixes.

Comment: This is the reason why i use .bind(this) in my own try of an answer. What do you mean with "regular prefixes"?

Comment: Just call the methods `.syncOrdersStop` and `.syncOrdersStart` (or with underscores).

Comment: Yes, but this is what i have recommended in my own answer as type of conclusion! Which you have "-1"ed

Answer (score -1):

Looking a bit more around, i found out it can be written like this:

```
function Controller () {
    this.OrdersSyncFreq = 3000; //ms
    this.syncOrders();  // have to be called at init to make sure the definitions of start and stop will be active. 
}

Controller.prototype.syncOrders = function () {

    this.syncOrders.start = function () {
        console.log("Start was called, frequence is: ",this.OrdersSyncFreq);
    }.bind(this);   // .bind(this)  is needed to have access this of your controller instance


    this.syncOrders.stop = function () {
        console.log("Stop was called, frequence is: ",this.OrdersSyncFreq);
    };

}

// run the code
var app = new Controller();
app.syncOrders.start();  // console: Start was called, frequence is:  3000
app.syncOrders.stop();  // console: Stop was called, frequence is:  undefined
```

The methodes of syncOrders - Start() and Stop() do not need to be prototyped, because syncOrders will not instantiated.

Anyhow I'm not sure if it really make sense to do it like this. I did it only because of the namespacing. may be it is better to use something more simple like `syncOrdersStart()` and `syncOrdersStop()` instead.

Comment: This overwrites `syncOrders.start` and `syncOrders.stop` every time a new instance is created.

Comment: yes this is ok. it will be instantiated only 2 times in my case. Anyhow, was the reason why i have written  "I'm not sure if it really make sense"...

Comment: BTW: I have written my question about 20 minutes. Than i found something like a solution. So to don't get negative points here (because of duplicate question or what ever), I decided to answer the question in which i still invested time by my self and invested again 30 minutes. And now i get negative points for this. this is no good learning!

Comment: Problem starts when this answer hangs around and people start finding wrong answers, through search engines, marked as correct just for keeping points. THEN, you'll have bad learning experience.

Comment: You don't loose points because of unanswered or duplicate questions. An answer gets downvotes if it is considered bad advise by someone, or when the proposed solution does not work.

Comment: No, this is not ok. `var a = new Controler, b = new Controler; b.OrdersSyncFreq = 6000; a.syncOrders.start()` - guess what this will log. If you absolutely want to use this syntax, [you have to create a new `syncOrders` for every `Controler` instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884096/organize-prototype-javascript-while-perserving-object-reference-and-inheritance).

Comment: to be sure if have tied it. a.syncOrders.start() will log "Start was called, frequence is:  3000",   b.syncOrders.start() will log "Start was called, frequence is:  6000". This is exactly what i need. the sync times for both instances need to be able to be different, because a and b will be used to sync different types of data.

Comment: I sync the amazon (b) orderlist from and (a) orderitems. The order list (which holds 100 orders) need to be refreshed only once a minute, but the orderitems request need to be done each 2 seconds. because it delivers only the items for 1 order (and throttling applies).