# Overriding a method of an inherited object

Tags: javascript, prototype-chain

I have the following code:

```
var Base = function () {
    // do stuff
}

Base.prototype.foo = function () {
    console.log("foo");
}

Base.prototype.someMethods = {
   methodOne: function () {
     console.log("methodOne");
   },
   methodTwo: function () {
     console.log("methodTwo");
   }
};

var myClass = function () {
    Base.call(this);
}

myClass.prototype = Object.create(Base.prototype);
myClass.constructor = myClass;

myClass.prototype.foo = function () {
    console.log("myClass")
    Base.prototype.foo.call(this);
};

myClass.prototype.someMethods.methodOne = function () {
   console.log("myClass");
   Base.prototype.someMethods.call(this);
};
```

When an instance of `myClass` is created a call to `myClass.foo()` will work as expected.  It will calls the `myClass` method then calls upon the base constructor method as part of that logic.

However, `myClass.prototype.someMethods.methodOne` will actually overwrite `Base.prototype.someMethods.methodOne`  (`console.log(Base.prototype.someMethods.methodOne)` displays the myClass function).

As a result, the call to `Base.prototype.somemethods.call(this)` creates infinite recursion.

Can you please explain to me why this is?  How is the prototype chain being created differently for the methods of the `someMethods` object?

What do I need to know to get this code working properly.?

Comment: `Base.prototype.somemethods` doesn't have a `call` method. Did you mean `Base.prototype.somemethods.methodOne`?

Comment: [Don't try to nest methods. Just don't.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884096/organize-prototype-javascript-while-perserving-object-reference-and-inheritance) If you absolutely want nesting, make `somemethods` an instance of its own proper class with an appropriate inheritance chain