# Nest class' methods in objects, but keep instance scope

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, ecmascript-6

I realized I don't know how to do something I think is pretty important, which is to create a 'subclass', or in other words a nested object upon an instance which has functions which refer to the instance.

For example, I would like to be able to do this:

```
sequence = new Sequencer(2, [true, true])
sequence.is_valid # returns true or false
```

using the following code:

```
class Sequencer

  Validations:

    correct_sequence_length: ->
      @division == @sequence.length

    positive_length: ->
      @division > 0

  constructor: (args) ->
    { @sequence, @division } = args

  is_valid: ->
    @Validations.correct_sequence_length() &&\
    @Validations.positive_length()
```

However it seems that since `Validations` is an object, it has its own scope and the `this` in its methods doesn't refer to the instance, but rather the `Validations` object. This means it can't access `@sequence` or `@tempo`. I also tried using an arrow function but it didn't work.

Is the best way to deal with this to make `Validations` its own class?

Comment: Coffeescript or ES6? Please decide, they're quite different.

Comment: [Yes, you need an extra class](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15884096/1048572) if you want to nest properties.

Comment: @Bergi I prefer coffeescript, but v2 outputs ES6 classes so it's not necessarily unrelated. If you have a solution that works in ES6 but not coffeescript I'd be curious to see it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll need an extra class that contains a reference to the `Sequencer`:

```
class Sequencer

  @Validations: class
    constructor: (@target) ->

    correct_sequence_length: ->
      @target.division == @target.sequence.length

    positive_length: ->
      @target.division > 0

  constructor: ({ @sequence, @division }) ->
    @validations = new Sequencer.Validations(@)

  is_valid: ->
    @validations.correct_sequence_length() &&
    @validations.positive_length()
```

(for convenience I nested it as a static property of `Sequencer`, but there's no need for that).

---

Arrow functions would work if you didn't make `validations` an object:

```
class Sequencer

  constructor: ({ @sequence, @division }) ->

  validations: ->
#             ^^^^
    correct_sequence_length: =>
      @division == @sequence.length

    positive_length: =>
      @division > 0

  is_valid: ->
    v = @validations()
    v.correct_sequence_length() && v.positive_length()
```

You can create that object with the arrow functions in the constructor as well:

```
class Sequencer

  constructor: ({ @sequence, @division }) ->
    @validations =
      correct_sequence_length: =>
        @division == @sequence.length
      positive_length: =>
        @division > 0

  is_valid: ->
    @validations.correct_sequence_length() &&
    @validations.positive_length()
```