# how to create methods in methods in es6 class

Tags: javascript, es6-class

Good day,

I dont know if am can explain this well for you to help but  i will like to use a an ES6 class to create an object that can be called like this.
var = varaibles
obj = objects

```
obj.var
obj.var.method
obj.var.var.method
obj.method.var
```

and so on.

I can only do one step

```
obj.var && obj.method
```

i will kind appreciate if one can help me here thanks

this is what i have done

```
class Table extends someClass {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.column = {
      sort: () => {
        console.log("firing");
      },
      resize: () => {
        console.log("firing");
      }
    };

    this.cells = {
      edit: () => {
        console.log("firing");
      }
    };
  }

  myMethods() {
    //BLAH
  }
}
```

Comment: your are saying that `let table = new Table()` and `table.cells.edit()` is not working?

Comment: I tested it, it ran properly.

Comment: No, [don't do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884096/organize-prototype-javascript-while-perserving-object-reference-and-inheritance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood, here is my solution.

If I return a object full of methods, I can use that object as I like.

```
class someClass {

  // this is a parent method
  Parent() {
    console.log(`From a Parent`)
  }

  // a getter that returns an object
  get parentWithChild() {
    return {
      child() {
        console.log(`From a Child`)
      }
    }
  }

  // a function that returns an object
  Methods() {
    return {
      child() {
        console.log(`From a Child`)
      }
    }
  }
}

const cool = new someClass();
cool.Parent(); // From a Parent
cool.parentWithChild.child(); // From a Child
cool.Methods().child(); // From a Child
```

You can use similar pattern on the extended class too.

Comment: Thanks, I didnt know return keyword works like that.