# Call Nested Function Within Prototype Method And Return Promise

Tags: javascript, promise, prototype

**Use Case:** I have users that need a relatively simple dot-notation that also handles a significant amount of asynchronicity. I have been tinkering with a pattern that is most likely verging into a closure. The pattern includes:

1. Initial function definition
2. Prototype method declaration
3. Functions within prototype that typically will return a value or promise.

**Outcome:** I would like a user to be able to access these methods in the format:

ParentFunction.prototype_method.nested_function(args);

**Problem**
Right now I am seeing various undefined issues and since I am designing this to be a rather large API implementation, I am unsure whether this pattern is most appropriate. Since I come from a Java background I prefer this type of approach if at all possible, and my end goal is to make the implementation of the API as readable and accessible as possible for junior users.

**Sample Source**

```js
//Parent function
var Actor = function(model, timings, options) {
  this.model = {
    "node": node
  };

  this.timings = timings;
  this.options = options;
};

//Sample prototype method
Actor.prototype.eventController = function() {
    var self = this;

    var clickEvent = function() {
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          try {
            $(self.model.node).trigger('click');
            resolve(true);
          } catch (error) {
            resolve(false);
          }
        }, self.timings.click);
      });
    }

    var mouseOverEvent = function() {
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          try {
            $(self.model.node).trigger('mouseover');
            resolve(true);
          } catch (error) {
            resolve(false);
          }
        }, self.timings.mouseover);
      });
    }

//Instantiate parent function
var actor = new Actor();

//Access nested function within prototype method then handle promise result
actor.eventController.clickEvent.then(...);
```

Comment: Is `eventController` supposed to be a function or an object?  Your implementation says the former; the sample usages says the latter.

Comment: for people like you, `class` was introduced in js :)

Comment: @JonasW. I looked into it a bit but did not see massive advantages to this approach. Would you have a basic example where I could create the notation I mentioned at the bottom of my example?

Comment: @ScottSauyet You are correct it would be an object.

Comment: @JonasW: I'm not a big user of `class`, so I may be missing something simple, but is there a way using it to set non-function prototype properties?  Obviously functions are easy.  ("methods", I guess, more accurately.)  But I don't know how to set a shared object using the `class` syntax.

Comment: Ignoring promises, [using "nested" prototype structures is asking for trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884096/organize-prototype-javascript-while-perserving-object-reference-and-inheritance). Just don't do that. (Surely something like that isn't possible in Java either?)

Comment: @ScottSauyet yeah wont help here, just a sidenote concerning  `and my end goal is to make the implementation of the API as readable and accessible as possible`

Answer (score 0):

Rather than messing about with prototypes, what if your constructor function set the properties you need?

```js
// dummy version for testing
const $ = (elt) => ({trigger: function(evt) {console.log(`${evt} on ${elt}`)}})

const makeHandler = (obj, evtName) => () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    try {
      $(obj.model.node).trigger(evtName);
      resolve(true);
    } catch(error) {
      resolve(false);
    }
  }, obj.timings[evtName]);
});

function Actor(foo) {
  this.model = {node: foo};
  // don't know where these would come from.  Hard-coding here.
  this.timings = {
    click: 150,
    mouseover: 100
  };
  this.eventController = {
    clickEvent: makeHandler(this, 'click'),
    mouseOverEvent: makeHandler(this, 'mouseover')
  } 
}

var actor1 = new Actor('abc');
var actor2 = new Actor('def');

actor1.eventController.clickEvent().then(console.log, console.log);
actor2.eventController.mouseOverEvent().then(console.log, console.log);
```

You could also replace that with a factory function:

```
function actor(foo) {
  const obj = {
    model: {node: foo},
    timings: {
      click: 150,
      mouseover: 100
    }
  };
  obj.eventController = {
    clickEvent: makeHandler(obj, 'click'),
    mouseOverEvent: makeHandler(obj, 'mouseover')
  };
  return obj; 
}

var actor1 = actor('abc');
var actor2 = actor('def');
```

(And of course this could all be cleaned up a bit with a dose of ES6 arrow functions.)