# JavaScript - Access Class Instance Property in Prototype Function

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
class Pet {
    constructor(name) {
        this.petName = name;
    }
}

Pet.prototype.speak = {
    name: function() {
        console.log(this.petName);
    }
};

// -----------------------------------------------

const myPet = new Pet("Max");
myPet.speak.name();
```

I expect this code to print `Max`, but instead it prints `undefined`.

If I change the console.log to `console.log(this);` it prints `{ name: [Function: name] }`. Which makes me think that function doesn't have access to the instance properties.

How can I ensure that this function has access to the instance?

Comment: 1. name refers to the function, it should be petName. 2. `this` doesn't refer to the object anymore but instead to the object the function is called in (in this case the object containing only the name() method)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're targetting or have support for ES6 language features, one way to achieve what you want would be via a `get` method combined with an `arrow function`.

The `get` method would be declared `get speak()` which means it can be called without paranthesis. This method would return an object that contains a `name()` arrow function. Use of the arrow function here allows you to access the enclosing `Pet` instance via the `this` keyword directly:

```js
class Pet {
    constructor(name) {
        this.petName = name;
    }
    
    // Get method allows the speak method to be called without ()
    get speak() {
      return {
        // Arrow function causes this.petName to refer to petName 
        // field of this class instance 
        name: () => {
          console.log(this.petName);
        }
      }
    }
}
 
const myPet = new Pet("Max");
myPet.speak.name();

const yourPet = new Pet("Min");
yourPet.speak.name();
```

Here is more information on the [get method syntax and language feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get).

Comment: I think this might work. Going to try it soon. Not quite the way I was thinking of it working. But it should work I think.

Comment: @CharlieFish sure, let me know if you have any questions or need anything clarified on this

Comment: Awesome. I think this will work. One last question tho. How does this differ from using a prototype? I know prototypes tend to be better in terms of memory usage and performance a bit. Does this behave similarly to that, or does it have the same problems as the non-prototype based solutions?

Comment: @CharlieFish great to hear this has helped - please consider accepting the answer if it meets your requirements. Sorry I can't give your answer justice in this small comment area however you will find this article useful for clarification https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-s-the-difference-between-class-prototypal-inheritance-e4cd0a7562e9

Comment: @Charlie `class` is basically just syntactic sugar for prototypes. With this answer, the `speak` getter is defined on `Pet.prototype`, but speak.name is recreated each time that getter is called.

Answer (score 1):

When you call a function like this: `myPet.speak.name();` then inside that function `this` refers to `myPet.speak`. In your case that is an object with one property (name) whose value is a function.

If you make `speak` itself be a function instead of an object, and use the property `petName` instead of `name`, it will work:

```js
class Pet {
    constructor(name) {
        this.petName = name;
    }
}

Pet.prototype.speak = function() {
    // myPet has a `petName` property, but no `name` property
    console.log(this.petName);
};

const myPet = new Pet("Max");
myPet.speak(); // this will be `myPet` inside the function
```

Comment: The goal is to have `myPet.speak` be an object, and `name` to be a method of that, that logs the name. This is to make the API as easy as possible.

Comment: @CharlieFish [That's not easy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884096/organize-prototype-javascript-while-perserving-object-reference-and-inheritance). Better just call the method `speakName`.

Comment: @Pual but if I use `arrow function` like this `Pet.prototype.speak = () => this.petName` this will not work